# Error in lifting method to function

Tags: scala, implicit-parameters

I have a method that with the implicit parameter. i get a error when i convert it to function in 2 case :

1:

```
def action(implicit i:Int) =  i + " in action"
val f = action _
```

then i get a StackOverflowError.

2：

```
def action(implicit i:Int) =  i + " in action"
val f = action(_)
```

then i get a error: missing parameter type

I must write like this :

```
val f = (i:Int) => action(i)
```

that's ok. And if the parameter of 'action' is not the implicit , all case are right. So how to explain , and what i miss ?

Comment: What are you attempting to do? You appear a little confused about what an `implicit` argument is (you wouldn't be the only one), and what the meaning of the `_` is. Are you perhaps thinking of a partial function? Can you give an example of what you're trying to do with this code?

Comment: thanks for your response. Sorry , i have no example , i'm a green bean in Scala :) . Now i just want to feel the method with implicit, and i want to know whether it can be using as a general method . I assume a case : I def a method with implicit parameter and some place i need reused it as a general method.  But i get the error , i do not know what happend, so i think i must lost some knowledge in scala . i need a help .

Comment: I've updated my answer with better examples and some further explanation. If you have any questions about the answer, may we should switch to a discussion...

Comment: Aha! You get a `StackOverflow` **in the compiler**! That changes the question completely. You should *never ever* be able to crash the compiler, not even with invalid code (which BTW I *don't* think your code is). Note that the fact that the crash is *in the compiler* vs in your code is *really* important and should have been included in the question from the beginning.

Comment: @JörgWMittag . My code was in Scala REPL and just 2 line above.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is pretty unique, I guess, since you wouldn't want to do this for an `implicit` parameter (partly because you'd lose the benefits of that value being filled with an `implicit` value by the compiler in the lifted version). @Milk, I think you should file this as a bug. In the second case, you should use `val f = action(_: Int)` and you're OK.

Comment: File _Scala_ compiler bugs [here](https://github.com/scala/bug).

Comment: @Milk Actually, it appears that [this issue](https://github.com/scala/bug/issues/10299)  has already been reported.

Comment: @MikeAllen OK, I see . Thanks very much.

Comment: @Milk: You should have told us from the very beginning that the bug is in the compiler, not in your code. That information is *extremely* important to answer this question, and I only discovered it by accident. This information is *still* missing from the question. There is still no information about the error you are getting other than that it's a stack overflow. But the fact that the stack overflow happens not in your code but in the compiler, and not during run time but during compile time is *vital* to answering this question, because it quite simply means that there is nothing wrong with

Comment: … your code and the problem is in the compiler. It would have been much easier to figure out the problem if you hadn't excluded this information from your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you specify a parameter to a function to be `implicit`, you are inviting the compiler to supply the value of that parameter for you. So how does the compiler find those values? It looks for values of the same type (`Int` in your case) that have been declared as `implicit` values in a variety of *scopes*.

(For simplicity, I'll just use a local scope in this example, but you might want to read up on this topic. [Programming in Scala, 3rd Ed](https://www.artima.com/shop/programming_in_scala_3ed) is a good first step.)

Note that the names of the `implicit` values are ignored and have no bearing on proceedings, the compiler only looks at the types of `implicit` values. If multiple `implicit` values with the required type are found in the same scope, then the compiler will complain about *ambiguous implicit values*.

For example, the following provides a function with an implicit parameter and a default value for that parameter within the current scope:

```
def greetPerson(name: String)(implicit greeting: String) = s"$greeting $name!"
implicit val defaultGreeting = "Hello" // Implicit value to be used for greeting argument.
val y = greetPerson("Bob") // Equivalent to greetPerson("Bob")(defaultGreeting).
val z = greetPerson("Fred")("Hi")
```

Note that `y` is just a `String` value of `"Hello Bob!"`, and `z` is a string with the value `"Hi Fred!"`; neither of them are functions.

Also note that `greetPerson` is a *curried function*. This is because `implicit` parameters cannot be mixed with regular, non-`implicit` parameters in the same parameter list.

In general, it's bad practice to use common types (`Int`, `Boolean`, `String`, etc.) as values for `implicit` parameters. In a big program, there might be a lot of different `implicit` values in your scope, and you might pick up an unexpected value. For that reason, it's standard practice to wrap such values in a *case class* instead.

If you're trying to create a value that supplies some of the arguments of another function (that is, a *partially applied function*), then that would look something like this:

```
def greetPerson(greeting: String, name: String) = s"$greeting $name!"
val sayHello = greetPerson("Hello", _: String)
val y = sayHello("Bob") // "Hello Bob!"
val sayHi = greetPerson("Hi", _: String)
val z = sayHi("Fred") // "Hi Fred!"
```

In both cases, we're creating *partially applied functions* (`sayHi` and `sayHello`) that call `greetPerson` with the `greeting` parameter specified, but which allow us to specify the `name` parameter. Both `sayHello` and `sayHi` are still only values, but their values are *partially applied functions* rather than constants.

Depending upon your circumstances, I think the latter case may suit you better...

I would also read up on how the underscore character (`_`) is used in *Scala*. In a partially applied function declaration, it corresponds to the arguments that will be provided later. But it has a lot of other uses too. I think there's no alternative to reading up on *Scala* and learning how and when to use them.

Comment: Thanks for your time . I get something from your response , e.g. partially applied function . Maybe my question was too vaguely .  Let me to explain : The point in my question was convert (lift) the method to function .  In general method (all parameter are explicit )  "action _" and "action(_)" and "(i:Int) => action(i)" will pass the compiling. i.e. They can be lift to a function . But if the method with implicit parameter , then the compiler can not to lift it to function and give me different response in my different case. Yes i know how to avoid this error , but i want to know what i miss